# How to make decimal to fraction calculator work

Tags: c++

I am having trouble making a program that converts decimals to fractions work in c++. I have pasted the code below and am open to any suggestions.

```
int main()
{
    char n = 0;//for decimal point
    char x = 0;//for tenths place
    char y = 0;//for hundredths place
    std::cout << "Please enter the decimal to the hundredths place here: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cin >> y;
        if (x == 0)
            std::cout << 0 << y << "/100";
        if (y == 0)
            std::cout << x << "/10";

        if (y == 1 || y == 2 || y == 3 || y == 4 || y == 5 || y == 6 || y == 7 || y == 9)
            std::cout << x << y << "/100";

}
```

Comment: *I am having trouble making a program that converts decimals to fractions work* -- Please ask a focused question.  What doesn't "work"?  And what happened to simply stating `if (y >= 1 && y <=9)` instead of that `if` statement you posted?

Answer (score 1):

You are taking char type input, and comparing it to int values. Try comparing to the char equivalent of the int values you use (i.e. '1' instead of 1). Also, your last if excludes the possibility of 8, which is weird in my opinion.

It would give something like this :

```
if (x == '0')
    std::cout << 0 << y << "/100";
if (y == '0')
        std::cout << x << "/10";

    if (y == '1' || y == '2' || y == '3' || y == '4' || y == '5' || y == '6' || y == '7' || y == '8' || y == '9')
        std::cout << x << y << "/100";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bettorun's answer, you also would need to do the same to your variables:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        char n = '0';//for decimal point
        char x = '0';//for tenths place
        char y = '0';//for hundredths place

        cout << "Please enter the decimal to the hundredths place here: ";
        cin >> n >> x >> y;

        if (x == '0')
            cout << '0' << y << "/100" << endl;

        if (y == '0')
            cout << x << "/10" << endl;

        else if (y == '1' || y == '2' || y == '3' || y == '4' || y == '5' || y == '6' || y == '7' || y == '9')
        cout << x << y << "/100" << endl;

        return 0;
}
```